# Setting foobar.com and www.foobar.com to point to my Amazon S3–hosted site

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, amazon-web-services

I have a website hosted at Amazon S3; the URL is something like `www.foobar.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. I would like to set my domain registrar (NameCheap) to redirect both `foobar.com` and `www.foobar.com` to this website. Setting the record

```
www.foobar.com CNAME www.foobar.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
```

works fine for the `www` subdomain. However, I can’t figure out how to configure the no-subdomain version of the site.  I tried

```
foobar.com CNAME www.foobar.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
```

but that doesn’t seem to work. (And did I read somewhere that CNAMEs aren’t supposed to be used like this?) I know that the S3 bucket name is supposed to be identical to the fully-qualified DNS name, but does this really mean that I need to mirror my website contents in two different buckets? I feel like there must be a better solution than that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot serve "domain apex" content from S3-hosted websites.  The easiest solution is to configure your domain such that "foobar.com" is redirected to "www.foobar.com". Unfortunately this requires you to run a HTTP server with a rewrite rule to enforce it.

I can't vouch personally for the service but http://www.wwwizer.com/ offers a free apex to www redirect service.

Comment: This is longer accurate, although it was when it was written.  This is now possible with Alias records if the domain is hosted in Route 53.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like AWS S3 added [bucket redirection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) around the end of 2012 to allow support for www.foobar.com and foobar.com