# Amazon s3 bucket congigured as static web site . is it possible" .s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" not to show in the url of the served pages

Tags: amazon-s3

Amazon s3 bucket congigured as static web site . is it possible
"http://.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" not to show 
 in the url of the served pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to point a domain to serve static site from Amazon S3? (not sub-domain)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169422/how-to-point-a-domain-to-serve-static-site-from-amazon-s3-not-sub-domain)

Comment: Also of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281741/setting-foobar-com-and-www-foobar-com-to-point-to-my-amazon-s3-hosted-site

Comment: Duplicate, yes, but also, both of those questions have accepted answers that are no longer accurate.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169422/how-to-point-a-domain-to-serve-static-site-from-amazon-s3-not-sub-domain#21562853) is the correct one and includes a link to a tutoral -- "alias" records in Route 53 allow static web sites at the apex of a domain.  Also, now, one bucket can redirect to another, allowing addition or removal of "www".